# Scrapy ignores formatted data when scraping tables

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm attempting to scrape UFC dates from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events using CSS selectors. However I'm finding that if there's any data in a cell surrounding by additional tags such as `<b></b>` or `<a></a>` or `<p></p>` the data does not get scraped at all.

I've attempted using `.getall()` and `.extract_first()` and these both provide the same output. What am I missing?

Tag on question. How can I scrape a table with a specific id?

```
import scrapy

class UFCEVENTSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ufcevents"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self, response):

        #TODO
        # row.css calls ignore data if it has html tags around it such as <b>13</b>

        for row in response.css("tbody tr"):

            ## Use the below to output to console
            ##
            #event = row.css("td:nth-child(1)::text").get()
            #date = row.css("td:nth-child(2)::text").get()
            #venue = row.css("td:nth-child(3)::text").get()
            #location = row.css("td:nth-child(4)::text").get()
            #ref = row.css("td:nth-child(5)::text").get()
            #notes = row.css("td:nth-child(6)::text").get()

            #ufce = UFCEvent(date, eventtype, dead, injured, location)
            #ufce.displayEvent()

            ## Use the below to create a json file with
            ## scrapy crawl terrorism -o terrorism.json
            yield{
                "event": row.css("td:nth-child(1)::text").getall(),
                "date": row.css("td:nth-child(2)::text").extract_first(),
                "venue": row.css("td:nth-child(3)::text").extract_first(),
                "location": row.css("td:nth-child(4)::text").extract_first(),
                "ref": row.css("td:nth-child(5)::text").extract_first(),
                "notes": row.css("td:nth-child(6)::text").extract_first()
            }


class UFCEvent:

    def __init__(self, event, date, venue, location, ref, notes):
        self.event = event
        self.date = date
        self.venue = venue
        self.location = location
        self.ref = ref
        self.notes = notes

    def displayEvent(self):
        print ("Event : ", self.event,  ", Date: ", self.date, ", Venue: ", self.venue, ", Location: ", self.location, ", Reference: ", self.ref, ", Notes: ", self.notes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using selector like this `row.css("td:nth-child(1)::text").getall()` you can get text only from `td` tag, if need text from `td` tag and its children you have to use selector like this one:

```
row.css("td:nth-child(1) ::text").getall()
```

need to add `space` before `::` to get children text as well

you need to make following changes in your code:

```py
....
yield{
                "event": row.css("td:nth-child(1) ::text").getall(),
                "date": row.css("td:nth-child(2) ::text").extract_first(),
                "venue": row.css("td:nth-child(3) ::text").extract_first(),
                "location": row.css("td:nth-child(4) ::text").extract_first(),
                "ref": row.css("td:nth-child(5) ::text").extract_first(),
                "notes": row.css("td:nth-child(6) ::text").extract_first()
            }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

To scrape a table with a specific id, do the following. Inspect the page in your webbrowser and find the id of the table. e.g. `<table id="Scheduled_events" ...`

Then to scrape only that table use this, the `table` targest all tables, and `#Scheduled_events` adds that that table must have the id after the #:

```
 for row in response.css("table#Scheduled_events tbody tr"):
     ...
```

Comment: thank you, that fixed the problem in the tag on question nicely.